# how to find total play time of each week for the given date in python?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, if-statement

I have a data frame that looks like the one below

```
k={'user_id':[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5],
   'created':[ '2/09/2021','2/10/2021','2/16/2021','2/17/2021','3/09/2021','3/10/2021','3/18/2021','3/19/2021',
              '2/19/2021','2/20/2021','2/26/2021','2/27/2021','3/09/2021','2/10/2021','2/18/2021','3/19/2021',
             '3/24/2021','3/30/2021',],
   'stop_time':[11,12,13,14,15,25,26,27,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,25,26],
  'play_time':[10,11,12,13,14,24,25,26,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13,24,25]}

df=pd.DataFrame(data=k)

df['created']=pd.to_datetime(df['created'], format='%m/%d/%Y')
df['total_play_time'] = df['stop_time'] - df['play_time']
```

[image]

Now we need to use the first date of each user_id as the first-week start date for example we need to select the '2/9/2021' is the first-week start date of user_id 1 and '3/09/2021' as the first-week start date of user_id 2.

we need sum the total playtime each week of user_id its continue to give a sum of each until the current date(for example if run report to today its has to give sum of each week until today)  and give the result as below

```
ID  week1   week2     week3  week4  week5  week6 week7  week8     week9  week10  week11  week12
1   3        2        0      0      0      0     0      0         0       0       0      0
2   1        2        0      0      0      0     0
```

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```py
# Get a list of unique id's
user_ids = df["user_id"].unique()

# Get the start date of each user
start_dates = [min(df[df["user_id"]==usr]["created"]) for usr in user_ids]

# We will subtract the start date to have a common baseline for all users
df["time_since_start"] = None
for i, usr in enumerate(user_ids):
    df.loc[df["user_id"]==usr,"time_since_start"] = df.loc[df["user_id"]==usr,"created"] - start_dates[i]
# we got a Timedelta object, but its more useful as a float
df['t'] = [x.value for x in df["time_since_start"]]

# get the maximum time any user has ever ..played? to make our bins
max_time = df["time_since_start"].max()
# convert it from microseconds to weeks, rounding up
max_weeks = int(np.ceil(max_time.value/8.64e+13/7))

# make the bins and add corresponding readable labels
bins = [pd.Timedelta(weeks = wk).value for wk in range(max_weeks+1)]
labels = ["week " + str(wk+1) for wk in range(max_weeks)]

# bin the data and aggregate the result
df["bin"] = pd.cut(df['t'], bins, labels = labels)
df.groupby(['user_id','bin'])['total_play_time'].sum()
```

```
user_id  bin   
1        week 1    2
         week 2    1
         week 3    0
         week 4    1
         week 5    0
         week 6    0
2        week 1    0
         week 2    2
         week 3    0
         week 4    0
         week 5    0
         week 6    0
3        week 1    2
         week 2    1
         week 3    1
         week 4    0
         week 5    0
         week 6    0
4        week 1    0
         week 2    1
         week 3    0
         week 4    0
         week 5    0
         week 6    0
5        week 1    1
         week 2    0
         week 3    0
         week 4    0
         week 5    0
         week 6    0
Name: total_play_time, dtype: int64
```

You can then reshape the dataframe to a wide format if you really need to.

Comment: I am getting the following error while running your code.

Comment: AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-5404e86fc702> in <module>
      4     df.loc[df["user_id"]==usr,"time_since_start"] = df.loc[df["user_id"]==usr,"created"] - start_dates[i]
      5 # we got a Timedelta object, but its more useful as a float
----> 6 df['t'] = [x.value for x in df["time_since_start"]]
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'value'

Comment: By copy-pasting the code in your question and then my code, I wasn't able to reproduce this error.
pandas==1.2.4
numpy==1.20.2
python: 3.7.10
Platform: ubuntu 20.04